# PHP version issues with Zend server

Tags: php, zend-server

I am really really new programmer.

I have PHP 5.3 on my mac os x.

I recently installed Zend Server 6.1.0 for php version 5.4 and it exists in /usr/local/zend/bin

when i type which php it says /usr/bin/php

how do i get to use to one in /usr/local/zend/bin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make sure `/usr/local/zend/bin` is presented prior to `/usr/bin/` in your PATH environment variable.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/zend/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Did that...but its getting assigned back again :/

Comment: That way it survives reboots! might also consider /etc/zsh_profile if you're using zsh or someone else setup your system and you can't see it stay after a reboot or your terminal login looks something like this:

Last login: Fri Jun 19 14:06:33 on ttys001
mymac%